# Shorthand notation of representing a number of OR("|") operator statements

Tags: r

Assume a database in the format below:

```
 steps date       interval
   <dbl> <date>        <int>
 1     0 2012-10-01        0
 2     0 2012-10-01        5
 3     0 2012-10-01       10
 4     0 2012-10-01       15
 5     0 2012-10-01       20
 6     0 2012-10-01       25
 7     0 2012-10-01       30
 8     0 2012-10-01       35
 9     0 2012-10-01       40
10     0 2012-10-01       45
```

And I want to take out all the rows which have month as October (10) with dates between 1 to 10.

```r
a2 <- filter(y,(day(date)==1|day(date)==2|day(date)==3|day(date)==4|day(date)==5|day(date)==6|day(date)==7|day(date)==8|day(date)==9|day(date)==10) & month(date)==10)
```

Can someone give me a shorter and more versatile version of the above code?

Comment: Can you use `>=` and `<=`?

Comment: `a2 <- filter(y, (day(date)>=1 & day(date)<=10)&month(date)==10)` ?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and C?

Comment: And if you stick to OR and AND: logical operators are `||` and `&&`; `|` and `&` are bitwise operators

Comment: How is this related to the C and C++ programming languages? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: Why are you using bitwise operators rather than logical ones???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this if you can use the `>=` and `<=` operators.

```
a2 <- filter(y,(day(date)>=1 && day(date)<=10) && month(date)==10)
```

Comment: Please use `&&` instead of bitwise `&`

Comment: Isn't the result same for boolean operation?

Comment: Ok, I modified the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a doubt, Why are you asking the repeated questions?